# What is the difference between float64 and double in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow

In storing floating point values both overflow and underflow problems cause loss of data. In machine learning tasks underflow is a common problem. I wanted to know if `double` is better than `float64` in TensorFlow or not and if there is any difference between them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a look at tensorflow's `dtypes.py`, there's this line:

```
double = float64
```

So `double` is exactly the same at `float64`.

Comment: Might be worth noting that in general (including many C libraries unrelated to question), `double` tracks what the machine calls double precision (so may depend on processor or OS). Whilst `float64` is fixed. There may be a good reason why TensorFlow takes a shortcut here, such as it only works on machines where the two are the same in any case.